# How to download a specific CSV file from the server to the client using Save As dialog box in php?

Tags: php, csv, download

I have a file named CO2.csv on the server and I want the user through a button in a form to download and save it with a new file name to a whatever location in his hard drive.

this is the Html script of the button that calls the php code

```
 <form action="FCO2.php"  method="post" <?php if(empty($_SESSION["CO2"])){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?> >

    <input type="submit" value="Export to CSV" name="submit">

</form>
```

And here is the FCO2.php

```
<?php

$file = 'temp/CO2temp.csv';

if(!$file)
{ // file does not exist
    die('file not found');
} 
else 
{
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/csv");

}
?>
```

But it didn't work, it always create an empty file and never copies the file that is located on the server.

Comment: whats the porblem with the code above? (please don't say "it doesn't work")

Comment: The issue simply is that you never send the contents of the file. You check if it exists, then send headers, _and that's it_! You have to add something like `readfile()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/csv");`?! That isn't a transfer encoding value.

Comment: @Quentin so what is the right value then?

Answer (score 0):

oh your just missing a call to the actual file such as using `readfile`

so adding it in:

```
<?php

$file = 'temp/CO2temp.csv';

if(!$file)
{ // file does not exist
    die('file not found');
} 
else 
{
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: text/csv");
    readfile($file);
   exit;// good practice but if this is the whole file, its not needed

}
?>
```

Comment: @user3646906 your welcome, now learn about accepting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting a pile of headers, but your PHP ends before you output the file.

You can use [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) to do that.